# What font did J.R.R Tolkien use in 'The Lay of Aotrou & Itroun' manuscript?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

[image]

What font did J.R.R Tolkien use in 'The Lay of Aotrou & Itroun' manuscript (or what font would be a close match, here)?
https://www.pinterest.com.au/pin/765260161654947172/

Comment: Tolkien lived before the time of computers and ‘using fonts’ (outside of professional typesetters and printers). He wrote it by hand.

Comment: Something like https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/newrenaissance/edwards-uncial-1904/ could help you create a similar effect, though it won’t be as lively as a handwritten page.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That is an answer I'd upvote the Melkor out of.

Answer (score 4):

Tolkien used the font "
[Legendarium](https://www.behance.net/gallery/32472021/Legendarium-a-JRR-Tolkien-Script-Font) ". You can read about its development [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/32472021/Legendarium-a-JRR-Tolkien-Script-Font). Of course first he hand-wrote the manuscript, published it, got famous, and then created the font and a time-machine :)

Only joking of course. Obviously he hand-wrote it, but that font is a very detailed reproduction of his hand-writing.

I read recently there was a website of [Songwriter's Fonts](https://www.songwritersfonts.com/) - A very interesting resource. - EDIT - And sadly shut down due to copyright issues :( ...but the download links do still work on the [archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180409091058/https://www.songwritersfonts.com/) ;)

It's an odd question (and likely to be closed) but I thought the answer, and links, might interest you and others.

Comment: Have you visited that Songwriter's site?? -- "*we have to shut down this website because of legal issues*" `:)`

Comment: Oh no. I got the link from my history. That's a shame, it was great

Comment: Yeah it sounded interesting.. so I went to check it out.. no beuno `:)`

Comment: It was good while it lasted

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20180409091058/https://www.songwritersfonts.com/

Comment: Wow. I'm amazed the downloads still work at the web archive! I guess it really is true.. the internet is immortal and NOTHING ever truly vanishes `:)`